# How to structure a solidity project

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment

Very new to Solidity.
Found a intellij plugin in repository, now wondering what is the best way to structure the project?
For example npm js projects *usually* have have src folder and node_modules then a public folder (compiled, transpiled, minified and built code ends up) or www folder. So what about when i want to code/create a contract for a token Is there any suggested structure to be followed? Best practice? Or should solidity files be stored where the app scr code is? I apologize if my questions are super silly
My understanding so far is that contracts are written once (token code) and the Dapp would use those/distribute/sell/offer ??? But that is very likely a wrong understanding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You found an IntelliJ plugin in which repository? Somewhere under https://github.com/ethereum/ ? Is it a plugin to simplify Solidity coding in IntelliJ?

Comment: its under plugins in the WS, but that gives solidity type support and possibly more stuff...
The question is not ONLY related to the plugin, i am trying to explain the fact that this is very new to me and if anyone used this plugin and what are general guidelines as in how solidity code is/should be structured, as developers with experience (tend to) follow, best practices... When developing smart contracts/tokens

Comment: Yes, there is. Install truffle and then run `truffle init`. You'll get the folder structure recommended by truffle (which is something like: folder 'contracts', folder 'migrations' folder 'test' and file 'truffle-config.js').